# Login to a moodle website on google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

so i have been thinking recently i want to fetch some data from my moodle account using URLFetchApp. i want to get the html code but the login doesn't work. anyone have any guess what is going on? because it say session expired.

```
 function myFunctionx() {
  var payload={
     user_email:USER_NAME,
    user_password:USER_PASSWORD,
  };
  var option={
  "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload,
    "followRedirects" : true
  };
  var urlfetch=UrlFetchApp.fetch(MOODLE_WEBSITE,option);
  var sessionDetails=urlfetch.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];
    var downloadPayload = 
      {
       user_email:USER_NAME,
    user_password:USER_PASSWORD,
      };
  var downloadCsv = UrlFetchApp.fetch(MOODLE_SITE, 
                                  {"headers" : 
                                   {
                                     'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                                    "Cookie" : sessionDetails
                                   },
                                   "method" : "post",
                                   "payload" : downloadPayload,
                                  });
  DocumentApp.openById("1Osvvi4vYGx9hzvTr2qhQZj3xx_CFuL0wzhjeJQCuq7A").getBody().insertParagraph(0, urlfetch.getContentText());
Logger.log(downloadCsv.getContentText())
}
```

sorry i can't show the moodle site publicly. but let's just pretend the website url is in MOODLE_SITE constant

Thanks.